# Open Source Implementation of Checkers

Tags: java, tree

I am looking for an open source implementation of a checkers game to run some game tree searching experiments on. Does anyone know of an implementation?

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: Checkers is solved, white wins :P

Comment: Actually, it's a draw.  Look at https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn12296-checkers-solved-after-years-of-number-crunching/

Answer (score 2):

I found this on Google:
[Java Checkers](http://www.concentric.net/~Bereza/checkers/).

The source code is below it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Anyone else?

Comment: Here's one: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/books/extracts/javanotesv3/source/Checkers.java from the free, on-line textbook Introduction to Programming Using Java available at http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/.

Comment: That's an awful Checkers game. It doesn't even force you to jump!

Answer (score 2):

GUI checkers is the strongest opensource checkers engine. You can download the source code from the following link. http://www.3dkingdoms.com/checkers.htm